# Delphi XE6 issue with styled menus with invisible items

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Ever since upgrade to XE6 there seems to be a bug in the application menus when you use styles, best explained with these screenshots:

The 2nd screenshot has the "22" item Visible set to False

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi XE6 is using a outdated version of the [`VCL Styles Utils`](https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/) project to style the popup menus. This issue doesn't happen if the last version of the VCL Styles Utiles Project is used as replacement of the Embarcadero version. So as workaround you must download the VCL Styles Utils project from the [repository](https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/checkout), then add the units Vcl.Styles.Utils.Menus, Vcl.Styles.Utils.SysControls and Vcl.Styles.Utils.SysStyleHook  to your project and finally comment or remove the Line (27) `{$UNDEF UseVCLStyleUtilsMenu}` in the [Vcl.Styles.Utils.Menus](https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/browse/trunk/Common/Vcl.Styles.Utils.Menus.pas) unit.

Comment: @RRUZ I'm also seeing bugs in styles and, in my case, popup menus. Seems Embarcadero only ships beta versions :(. VCL Styles site says it only supports Delphi, any idea if it is possible to install in C++ Builder XE6?

Comment: Hi @MikeVersteeg, yes you can use the `VCL Styles Utils` in C++ Builder.